# Groupby and sum of multiple columns with the same value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working on Pandas data frame and have following dataframe:

```
data =pd.DataFrame()
data['HomeTeam'] = ['A','B','C','D','E']
data['AwayTeam'] = ['E','D','A','B','C']
data['HomePoint'] = [1,3,0,1,3]
data['AwayPoint'] = [1,0,3,1,0]
data ['Match']  = data['HomeTeam'].astype(str)+' Vs '+data['AwayTeam'].astype(str)
# I want to duplicate the match
Nsims = 2
data_Dub =pd.DataFrame((pd.np.tile(data,(Nsims,1))))
data_Dub.columns = data.columns
# Then I will assign the stage of the match
data_Dub['SimStage'] = data_Dub.groupby('Match').cumcount()
```

What i wanted to do is to sum homepoint and awaypoint obtained by each team and save it to new data frame.
my new dataframe will look like as follow:

[image]

It means that Homepoint and awaypoint will be added for same team as I have 5 teams in dataframe.
Can anyone advise how to do it.

I used following code and it does not work.

```
Point =  data_Dub.groupby(['SimStage','HomeTeam','AwayTeam])['HomePoint','AwayPoint'].sum()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum` separately for `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam`, then use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html), last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`, change column name and if necessary order of columns:

```
a = data_Dub.groupby(['AwayTeam', 'SimStage'])['AwayPoint'].sum()
b = data_Dub.groupby(['HomeTeam', 'SimStage'])['HomePoint'].sum()
s = a.add(b).rename('Point')

df = s.sort_index(level=[1, 0]).reset_index().rename(columns={'AwayTeam':'Team'})
df = df[['Team','Point','SimStage']]
print (df)
  Team  Point  SimStage
0    A      4         0
1    B      4         0
2    C      0         0
3    D      1         0
4    E      4         0
5    A      4         1
6    B      4         1
7    C      0         1
8    D      1         1
9    E      4         1
```